# Mount LVM volume as external usb drive? CentOS 6

Tags: filesystems, mount, hard-disk, lvm, usb-drive

I'm trying to mount my old 2x500GB drives to the new server which has the same drive volume. Both have LVM structure but it's not working.

```
root@server [/mnt/usb]# ls /dev/sd*  
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc1  /dev/sdd1  /dev/sde  
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdc   /dev/sdd   /dev/sdd2  /dev/sde1  

aroot@server [/mnt/usb]# pvscan  
  Couldn't find device with uuid 72VbNB-nT9K-DR4f-X39N-UsY6-LdIl-gJrYMp.  
  PV unknown device   VG vol_grp1   lvm2 [465.76 GiB / 0    free]  
  PV /dev/sdd1        VG vol_grp1   lvm2 [200.00 GiB / 192.00 MiB free]  
  PV /dev/sdb1        VG vg1        lvm2 [465.75 GiB / 0    free]  
  PV /dev/sdc1        VG vg1        lvm2 [465.75 GiB / 0    free]  
  Total: 4 [1.56 TiB] / in use: 4 [1.56 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]  

root@server [/mnt/usb]# pvdisplay  
  Couldn't find device with uuid 72VbNB-nT9K-DR4f-X39N-UsY6-LdIl-gJrYMp.  
  --- Physical volume ---  
  PV Name               unknown device  
  VG Name               vol_grp1  
  PV Size               465.76 GiB / not usable 3.02 MiB  
  Allocatable           yes (but full)  
  PE Size               4.00 MiB  
  Total PE              119234  
  Free PE               0  
  Allocated PE          119234  
  PV UUID               72VbNB-nT9K-DR4f-X39N-UsY6-LdIl-gJrYMp  

  --- Physical volume ---  
  PV Name               /dev/sdd1    
  VG Name               vol_grp1  
  PV Size               200.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB  
  Allocatable           yes  
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              51199
  Free PE               48
  Allocated PE          51151
  PV UUID               qdgwa6-ak5f-BU3a-ZC1F-noh2-oQSb-gJIC01

  --- Physical volume ---  
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1  
  VG Name               vg1  
  PV Size               465.76 GiB / not usable 11.99 MiB  
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               16.00 MiB
  Total PE              29808
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          29808
  PV UUID               j0vKFb-tcfa-h1oJ-YQDX-VCou-T1v9-p3lNWx

  --- Physical volume ---  
  PV Name               /dev/sdc1  
  VG Name               vg1
  PV Size               465.76 GiB / not usable 11.99 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               16.00 MiB
  Total PE              29808
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          29808
  PV UUID               WcoCeZ-ONzG-CCCn-T71g-W2GZ-9PHF-utuDZv

root@server[/mnt/usb]# lvscan  
  Couldn't find device with uuid 72VbNB-nT9K-DR4f-X39N-UsY6-LdIl-gJrYMp.  
  inactive          '/dev/vol_grp1/logical_vol1' [665.57 GiB] inherit  
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg1/lv_backup' [200.00 GiB] inherit  
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg1/lv_mysql' [150.00 GiB] inherit  
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg1/lv_home' [581.50 GiB] inherit  

root@server [/mnt/usb]# lvdisplay  
  Couldn't find device with uuid 72VbNB-nT9K-DR4f-X39N-UsY6-LdIl-gJrYMp.  
  --- Logical volume ---  
  LV Path                /dev/vol_grp1/logical_vol1  
  LV Name                logical_vol1  
  VG Name                vol_grp1
  LV UUID                6yh01x-n3SQ-Zcd4-BD0w-mM4G-qnBo-iGRN2i
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time nxserver1.gh-dns.com, 2013-08-25 18:32:27 +0100
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                665.57 GiB
  Current LE             170385
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---  
  LV Path                /dev/vg1/lv_backup  
  LV Name                lv_backup  
  VG Name                vg1  
  LV UUID                Qh1J15-K5Zy-JGYN-cWQ9-2eNV-GrfT-U8PuGL
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time host-83-142-228-15.rsclientdns.com, 2015-05-19 09:33:34 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                200.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---  
  LV Path                /dev/vg1/lv_mysql  
  LV Name                lv_mysql  
  VG Name                vg1  
  LV UUID                5WexHF-GOLE-IKv6-3j7K-IBvL-3UCC-bjHb89
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time host-83-142-228-15.rsclientdns.com, 2015-05-19 09:34:02 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                150.00 GiB
  Current LE             9600
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---  
  LV Path                /dev/vg1/lv_home  
  LV Name                lv_home  
  VG Name                vg1  
  LV UUID                BKvfUP-EyMx-MlU4-1q2C-MTkH-h1CC-Ip3Ba2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time host-83-142-228-15.rsclientdns.com, 2015-05-19 09:34:42 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                581.50 GiB
  Current LE             37216
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

I tried all possible commands to mount the 2 drives but not working. Kindly advise